# Force localeCompare to be case-sensitive

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

I'm trying to use JavaScript's [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function for sorting strings.

I was surprised by the results of running the following lines in the devTools console:

```
"a".localeCompare("b") // returns: -1
"A".localeCompare("b") // returns: -1
```

Another test:

```
"b".localeCompare("a") // returns: 1
"B".localeCompare("a") // returns: 1
```

Even when I am more specific about my sort I get the same result:

```
"a".localeCompare("b", { usage: "sort", sensitivity: 'variant' }) // -1
"A".localeCompare("b", { usage: "sort", sensitivity: 'variant' }) // -1
"b".localeCompare("a", { usage: "sort", sensitivity: 'variant' }) // 1
"B".localeCompare("a", { usage: "sort", sensitivity: 'variant' }) // 1
```

I want to use localeCompare to compare strings in a **case-sensitive** way, so shouldn't "b" compared to "a" and "B" compared to "a" have opposite results?

Comment: I was going to suggest supplying a `locales` argument, but, at least with `"en"` that didn't make a difference. Also tried the `"caseFirst"` option, but that didn't make a difference either, although it does say *Implementations are not required to support this property.*

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your confusion, how would `b` occur before `A` in the alphabetic order?

Comment: @Teemu I added another example in my question to show the opposite case...shouldn't "B" be before "a"?

Comment: Ehh... No, that would break the alphabetical order. If you need an order, in which all capitals come first, you've to implement your own sort function.

Comment: @Teemu ok so perhaps that is my confusion...I was thinking that the case-sensitive order would be ABCD...abcd..  Is that not correct?

Comment: That might be locale-dependent, afaik a case-sensitive order is `AaBbCcDd ...`. You can switch it to `aAbBcCdD` using `localeCompare` though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

LocalCompare can be case-sensitiv, enabled by `{ sensitivity: 'case'}` or the unicode extension: `u-kf-upper` or `u-kf-lower`.

The [spec of LocalCompare](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.9)  says, that:

> The result is intended to order String values in the sort order
>   specified by the system default locale

Or the locale you can add as argument.

The **default for en-US** for the case sensitive order is **"lower"** with:

```
aAbBcC ...
```

You could change it to **"upper"**, which is:

```
AaBbCc ...
```

---

This test shows that switching from `upper` to `lower` does only affect the same letter, and does not sort uppercase-alphabet before lowercase or visa versa.

```
var b = "A".localeCompare("a", 'en-US-u-kf-lower'); //  1
var c = "A".localeCompare("a", 'en-US-u-kf-upper'); // -1
var d = "A".localeCompare("b", 'en-US-u-kf-upper'); // -1
var e = "A".localeCompare("b", 'en-US-u-kf-lower'); // -1
```

---

- There might be a locale that sorts uppercase/lowercase differently, but I'm not aware of any...
- the international sort order is case insensitive
- ASCII sort order would be `ACb`
- Some locales have different orders: Finnish for example treads V like W: `Va Wb Vc` ...

---

**Does case-sensitivity affect numeric values in any way?**

```
var b = "1".localeCompare("a", 'en-US-u-kf-lower'); //  -1
var c = "1".localeCompare("A", 'en-US-u-kf-upper'); // -1
var d = "104".localeCompare("a", 'en-US-u-kf-upper'); // -1
```

no, but ...

**there is an option, how numeric values can be compared: `kn`**

with the option or Unicode extension `kn` one can enable numeric comparison (`kn-true`):

```
var b = "10".localeCompare("2", 'en-US-u-kn-true'); // 1
var c = "10".localeCompare("2", 'en-US'); // -1
```

However, numbers are always before letters:

```
var d = "1".localeCompare("a", 'en-US-u-kn-true'); // -1
var e = "1".localeCompare("a", 'en-US'); // -1
```

Comment: Any idea how to sort numbers after strings? like `"109".localCompare('a')`

Comment: @Vadorequest No, I don't think that's possible with localCompare.

Comment: Hi, I am trying sort on this array = [{name:"Acuityads"},{name:"alpha"}];. And I want alpha first. array.sort(function(a,b){return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, 'en-US'); })); it is returning Acuityads first. I am trying to achieve aAbBcC