# Sorting Nested Array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sort the given array by the property "title"

how can I sort it?
please help on how can I solve it. thanks.

```js
data = [
{
  _index: 'yo',
  _type: 'sample1',
  _id: '201',
  _score: null,
  _source: {
    type: 'digi',
    title: 'The Happy',
    description: 'san',
    image: 'good.jpg',
  },
  sort: [ sam ]
},
{
    _index: 'ya',
    _type: 'sample2',
    _id: '201',
    _score: null,
    _source: {
      type: 'sam',
      title: 'The lonely',
      description: 'san',
      image: 'y.jpg',
    },
    sort: [ sam ]
  },
  {
    _index: 'yi',
    _type: 'sample3',
    _id: '201',
    _score: null,
    _source: {
      type: 'sam',
      title: 'The Angry',
      description: 'sam',
      image: 'x.jpg',
    },
    sort: [ sam ]
  }
]
```

thanks

this is what I am trying

```
data.sort(function (x, y) {
    let a = x._source.title.toUpperCase(),
        b = y._source.title.toUpperCase();
    return a == b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1;
});
```

console.console(data);

But i am failing to access title.

Comment: `But i am failing to access title` what do you mean by this exactly? What are you getting right now, and what do you want it to return exactly?

Comment: A [mcve] of your code works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/h3jkceam/

Comment: Please make this an actual [mcve] that shows the described behavior and explain the problem you have (_"But i am failing to access title"_ is not enough) -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: or try with `localeCompare()`:

`data.sort((a,b) => a._source.title.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b._source.title.toLowerCase()))
`

Comment: @boxdox What does this change? OPs script works. And in case OP really struggles to get the content of the `title` property then your approach would also not work. And also there are better options for a [case-insensitive comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861386/force-localecompare-to-be-case-sensitive)